# set focus to a textBox in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Universal Windows Platform project that has a textBox element.
I'd like to set the focus to it when a Radio Button is clicked.

In the Radio Button click event, I can say:

```
txtBoxID.IsEnabled = true;
txtBoxID.Text = "";
```

But how do I set the focus? I saw some answers saying to use:

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(
```

but my FocusManager class doesn't have that method.

edit: Solved, thanks.  Just needed to know what argument to pass to SetFocus.  The other fellow's question which was thought to be similar was regarding an event occurring after he set focus to his control.

Comment: Give us some code of what you have tried so far. Have you  tried something like this `((Page)sender).Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);` or `txtBoxID.Focused = true;`?

Comment: try `txtBoxID.Focus()`

Comment: thank you for the responses, but in my project    txtBoxID.Focus()  throws an error.  same with     txtBoxID.Focused

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the code you need is:

```
txtBoxID.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Method is defined in [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#controls-and-focus).

Comment: Is there a way to set that in XAML?

Comment: Yes, see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872306/637425

Comment: @SynerCoder In UWP that won't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609832/uwp-navigation-example-and-focusing-on-control for where to put this. You must do this once the page has loaded.